Does the current Apache Flink Flamegraph allow for email alerts?
Does the current Apache Flink UI (as of 2023), Flamegraph allow for email alerts? We are trying to build an alerting system , and send of appropriate emails if a certain metric case is too high.

No. You'd need to integrate your own alerting platform with Flink's metrics. A couple of useful blogs:

https://flink.apache.org/2019/02/21/monitoring-apache-flink-applications-101/
https://www.ververica.com/blog/monitoring-large-scale-apache-flink-applications-part-1-concepts-continuous-monitoring

